# tfs analysis database sync

Tags: sql, tfs, analysis, sqlreportingservice

I have a job set up to Incrementally sync my analysis database in TFS 2015. This has been working without issue, up until recently where it now just runs and runs without completing.

The job never completes so there is no error message, but I am concerned that it will start to impact the operation of the system.

Can someone let me know;

1. Can I safely "kill" the job (What's the best way to do this?)
2. What I can do to stop this from happening repeatedly

Comment: What is this "job" you're referring to? The analysis database is automatically synchronized by the TFS job agent, you shouldn't need to do anything.

Comment: Suggest you add a screenshot show your job. Are you setting up your own customize job  to do the sync, or just TFS Analysis Services Sync job?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Analysis Services Sync job. You can try to follow the article below to manually process data warehouse and analysis services cube for Team Foundation Server. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400237.aspx

If manually processing still received the same issue, you can try to delete the Tfs_Analysis database and recreate it using TFS Admin Console. To delete the Tfs_Analysis database, you can connect to **Analysis Service** using **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**, expand the **Databases** node, and delete the Tfs_Analysis database.

> To recreate the Tfs_Analysis database, please refer to the following
>   steps:
>
> 1. Launch TFS Admin Console>>Application Tier>>Reporting, in the right panel, click **Edit** to open the **Reporting** windows.
> 2. Under the **Analysis Services** tab, input the Tfs_Analysis under **Database** textbox, and re-provide the required account under **Account for accessing data source**.
> 3. Click **Ok** to generate the Tfs_Analysis database in **Analysis Services**.
> 4. Click **Start Jobs** and **Start Rebuild** to rebuild warehouse and the Analysis Services database.